# xrandr config not loading properly at startup from .xprofile

Tags: ubuntu, boot, xrandr

I'm using `xrandr` to rescale the resolution on a netbook (Ubuntu 12.10).  When I run the following command it works fine:

```
xrandr --output LVDS1 --mode 1024x600 --panning 1280x720 --scale 1.25x1.2
```

However when I put that command into `.xprofile` to load it at startup the screen has a black border in the expanded area rather than the proper output.  I'm using exactly the same command so I'm not sure why it's not working.